# How to convert an Int value to a String?

Tags: string, type-conversion, integer, elm

How to convert an `Int` value to a `String`?

Comment: Please do not put tag names in the title. It's just noise. (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Agreed, though the bottom of the link has an example that includes the programing language in a conversational way, I think that still applies here.

Comment: No, it specifically says to avoid the form `[question title] in [tag]`. It adds nothing of value since the information is already in the tag.

Answer (score 4):

Elm makes this very easy with [`String.fromInt`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/1.0.5/String#fromInt).

For example

```
String.fromInt 5 -- returns "5"
```

A great tool to find answers to this is [elm-search](https://klaftertief.github.io/elm-search/). Just search for `Int -> String` or any other type signature for similar questions.